# Sql tables need help please

Tags: sql, delphi, crystal-reports

I'm trying to build a sql query which worked for the previous one which had 2 tables and it was pretty straight forward. This one though, has been driving me insane for 6 hours now.

The problem I have is that the results are only displayed should ALL criteria match and I don't want that. I would like the field to result back blank if it does not have an entry in the database.

I have a table and I want to display the orderrefno. At this point I want to check to see if a delivery note has been created and if so, I want to then see if an invoice has been created. Then report back to the report with the numbers of each but if they don't exist, the. It should just have the order no and the others would be both blank or just the invoice would be blank, should a delivery note been done.

I've tried building a query in crystal using inner, left join, right join, full but if an invoice does NOT exist I want it to list the delivery no and order no, but it won't.

I can do this in datasources and master sources in delphi and v studio, but would like to do a sql because the other easy is slow.

My tables are

- Project
- Order
- Calloff
- Calltodeliverylink
- Delivery
- Deliverytoinvoicelink
- Invoice

Tables are linked as follows.

Project.id is the main point of entry.
Then

Order.projectid -- project.id

Calloff.orderid -- order.id

Callofftodeliverylink.deliveryid -- call off.id

Delivery.id -- callofftodeliverylink.deliveryid

Deliverytoinvoicelink.deliveryid -- delivery.id

Invoice.id -- deliverytoinvoicelink.invoiceid

Many many thanks

EDIT:

Added Code. Sorry for FROM section being a mess. In crystal  drew the linking fields and asked it to show me the query and this is what it gave me.

```
SELECT 

 "Projects"."ID", "Orders"."IntOrderNo", "Deliveries"."DeliveryNo", "Projects"."InternalRef",    
 "CallOffs"."ID", "Customers"."Name", "Contacts"."Name", "Invoices"."InvoiceNo"


 FROM   

{oj (((((("GNManager"."dbo"."Invoices" "Invoices" LEFT OUTER JOIN "GNManager"."dbo"."DeliveryToInvoiceLink" "DeliveryToInvoiceLink" ON "Invoices"."ID"="DeliveryToInvoiceLink"."InvoiceID") LEFT OUTER JOIN "GNManager"."dbo"."Deliveries" "Deliveries" ON "DeliveryToInvoiceLink"."DeliveryID"="Deliveries"."ID") LEFT OUTER JOIN "GNManager"."dbo"."CallOffToDeliveryLink" "CallOffToDeliveryLink" ON "Deliveries"."ID"="CallOffToDeliveryLink"."DeliveryID") LEFT OUTER JOIN "GNManager"."dbo"."CallOffs" "CallOffs" ON "CallOffToDeliveryLink"."CallOffID"="CallOffs"."ID") LEFT OUTER JOIN ("GNManager"."dbo"."Projects" "Projects" LEFT OUTER JOIN "GNManager"."dbo"."Orders" "Orders" ON "Projects"."ID"="Orders"."ProjectID") ON "CallOffs"."OrderID"="Orders"."ID") INNER JOIN "GNManager"."dbo"."Customers" "Customers" ON "Orders"."CustomerID"="Customers"."ID") INNER JOIN "GNManager"."dbo"."Contacts" "Contacts" ON "Orders"."ContactID"="Contacts"."ID"}


 WHERE  

 "Projects"."InternalRef"='12/4169'

 ORDER BY 

 "Projects"."InternalRef" DESC, "Orders"."IntOrderNo" DESC
```

The above statement does work and produces everything that I need, but only if Invoices has an entry. If invoices is blank, nothing gets displayed.

Comment: Post your create and select queries.

Comment: or post URL to your test case on [sqlfiddle.com](http://sqlfiddle.com)

Comment: SELECT "Projects"."ID", "Orders"."IntOrderNo", "Deliveries"."DeliveryNo", "Projects"."InternalRef", "CallOffs"."ID", "Customers"."Name", "Contacts"."Name"
 FROM   {oj (((("GNManager"."dbo"."Deliveries" "Deliveries" LEFT OUTER JOIN "GNManager"."dbo"."CallOffToDeliveryLink" "CallOffToDeliveryLink" ON "Deliveries"."ID"="CallOffToDeliveryLink"."DeliveryID") LEFT OUTER

Comment: JOIN "GNManager"."dbo"."CallOffs" "CallOffs" ON "CallOffToDeliveryLink"."CallOffID"="CallOffs"."ID") LEFT OUTER JOIN ("GNManager"."dbo"."Projects" "Projects" LEFT OUTER JOIN "GNManager"."dbo"."Orders" "Orders" ON "Projects"."ID"="Orders"."ProjectID") ON "CallOffs"."OrderID"="Orders"."ID") INNER JOIN "GNManager"."dbo"."Customers" "Customers" ON "Orders"."CustomerID"="Customers"."ID") INNER JOIN "GNManager"."dbo"."Contacts" "Contacts" ON "Orders"."ContactID"="Contacts"."ID"}
 WHERE  "Projects"."InternalRef"='12/4169'
 ORDER BY "Projects"."InternalRef" DESC, "Orders"."IntOrderNo" DESC

Comment: Rich, [edit] your question and post your SQL there, where you can properly format it, not in the comments. You can format code by pasting it, selecting it all, and either clicking the tool button marked `{}` or pressing `Ctrl+K`. You can preview it right below where you're entering the question as you type or format it. If you need help while formatting, click the toolbar button marked `?` at the top right corner of the text input area. Taking time to properly format your post makes it more readable, and improves your chances of getting an answer. :-)

Comment: Thanks for the tip. I've done that now the best I can. Cheers

Comment: @pf1957: thanks for that link! Great resource.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The order of the tables in your join statement is the issue. Invoices being the first table is the one that will drive the rest of the results.

If you need all orders associated with your projects, no matter if there are any invoices, here's what I would do. Please note that you need valid values in Projects, Orders, Customers and Contacts, but everything else could be null.

```
select
    Projects.ID
    ,Orders.IntOrderNo
    ,Deliveries.DeliveryNo
    ,Projects.InternalRef
    ,CallOffs.ID
    ,Customers.Name
    ,Contacts.Name
    ,Invoices.InvoiceNo
from 
    Projects 
    join Orders on Orders.ProjectID = Projects.ID
    join Customers on Orders.CustomerID = Customers.ID
    join Contacts on Orders.ContactID = Contacts.ID
    left join Callofs on Callofs.OrderID = Orders.ID
    left join CallOffToDeliveryLink on CallOffToDeliveryLink.CallOffID = Callofs.ID
    left join Deliveries on CallOffToDeliveryLink.DeliveryID = Deliveries.ID 
    left join DeliveryToInvoiceLink on DeliveryToInvoiceLink.DeliveryID = Deliveries.ID
    left join Invoices on DeliveryToInvoiceLink.InvoiceID = Invoices.ID
where
    Projects.InternalRef = '12/4169'
order by
    Projects.InternalRef desc
    ,Orders.IntOrderNo desc
```

Comment: Hi. Thanks for posting. I've pasted the code and its still blank when no entry is matched in the invoice table because that job has not had an invoice produced yet.

Comment: I don't think that's the reason. Try removing the Contacts and Customers tables from the query. You _do_ have Orders associated to that Project, right?

Comment: I removed the reference to customers and contacts. Still blank. Everything on the project is finish but it's awaiting an invoice.

Comment: No, that's not it. Try removing the references to Invoices. Better yet, go back and try everything from the beginning: first Projects only, then Orders, etc.

Comment: did a reconnection and with Customers and Contacts removed. It does display entries in the fields with a blank in the invoice box. :) I will try a project now with no invoice and no delivery note raised but an order has been created. Wonder why customer threw the exception. cheers